# Unable to run Connexion 3 /w Flask - Middleware loads swagger twice

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi, connexion

I have created a openapi.yml file and initiated a connexion app and started the app without any errors.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/my_app
    /app
        __init__.py
        /api
            __init__.py
            api.py  # My API endpoint implementations
        /models
            __init__.py
            models.py  # My SQLAlchemy models
        swagger.yml  # OpenAPI specification
    .env
    config.py  # Configuration settings
    main.py  # Entry point for the application
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
connexion[swagger-ui, uvicorn, flask]==3.0.5
annotated-types==0.6.0
anyio==3.7.1
autopep8==2.0.4
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
connexion[swagger-ui, uvicorn, flask]==3.0.5
Flask==3.0.1
flask-sqlacodegen==2.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.6
inflect==7.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.4
mysqlclient==2.2.1
packaging==23.2
pycodestyle==2.11.1
pydantic_core==2.16.1
pydantic==2.6.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
sniffio==1.3.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.25
SQLAlchemy-serializer==1.4.1
starlette==0.32.0.post1
typing_extensions==4.9.0
uvicorn==0.27.1
Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

Inside the app/_*init_*.py I have defined the following function:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config, **kwargs):
    
    load_dotenv()

    # Create the Connexion application
    connex_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='./')
    
    connex_app.add_api("swagger.yml") #, base_path='/api/v1', arguments={'title': 'API v1'}, strict_validation=False, validate_responses=False, pythonic_params=True, name='api_v1_admin')

    application = connex_app.app

    # Load configuration from .env file
    application.config.from_object(config_class)
    application.config.update(kwargs)

    # initialize db connection
    from app.models import init_app
    init_app(application)
    
    return connex_app
```

From the main.py I am calling the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

The app starts without any error and the logs suggest that the app loaded the openapi file correctly.

```
INFO:     Started server process [17447]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.abstract:Adding /api/v1/agent...
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.abstract:Adding /api/v1/agent/{agentId}...
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json', 'application/xml']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json', 'application/xml']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.validation:Strict Request Validation: None
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json', 'application/xml']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.security:... Security: [{'admin_auth': ['write:agent', 'read:agent']}]
INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I have verified that my openapi yml file is syntactically correct.

The issue occurs when I try to call an api like so: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/agent/1

Connexion middleware tries to register the openapi endpoints again. Its evident from the logs below:

```
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.abstract:Adding /api/v1/agent...
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
DEBUG:connexion.middleware.abstract:Adding /api/v1/agent/{agentId}...
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:consumes: []
DEBUG:connexion.operations.openapi3:produces: ['application/json']
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/connexion/middleware/main.py", line 497, in __call__
    self.app, self.middleware_stack = self._build_middleware_stack()
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/connexion/middleware/main.py", line 338, in _build_middleware_stack
    app.add_api(
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask.py", line 141, in add_api
    self.app.register_blueprint(api.blueprint)
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/sansio/scaffold.py", line 45, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/sansio/app.py", line 599, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
  File "xxx/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/sansio/blueprints.py", line 310, in register
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The name '/api/v1' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51609 - "GET /api/v1/agent/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? Why connexion tries adding openapi's endpoints again?

Note: If I manually set routes, the project is working fine.

Comment: Your code snippet is incorrect / incomplete. You're calling `app.run()` but not showing how `app` is created. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added some more details. The app.run() is actually called from the main.py and is the reference to the connexion app instantiated inside the app module.
Just to be clear, it's a working Flask app which I am trying to migrate to Connexion.

Comment: Thanks @Qedrix, but it's still not possible to tell what is causing this issue. Please provide a minimal reproducible example which I can run myself to reproduce the error.